# Removing custom controls?

Tags: openlayers-2, mapcontrol

I am trying to remove custom draw controls from my OpenLayers application which I create like this:

```
var drawControls = {
     polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayerFreehand, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
     select: selectControl,
     box: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(boxLayer,
          OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
            handlerOptions: {
                sides: 4,
                irregular: true
            }
        }
    )
};
```

and which I add to the map like this:

```
for(var key in drawControls) {
            _map.addControl(drawControls[key]);
            }
```

I now would like to know how I can remove this custom control. I found examples for removing the standard OL controls like e.g. this

```
var ovMapControl = _map.getControlsBy("CLASS_NAME", "OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap")[0];
_map.removeControl(ovMapControl);
```

or

```
var ovMapControl = _map.getControlsBy('displayClass','olControlPanZoomBar')[0];
 _map.removeControl(ovMapControl);
```

but what is the 'displayClass' or the 'CLASS_NAME' in the case of custom controls like my 'drawControls'?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you still have access to drawControls object at the place you want to remove the controls, then you can do something like:

```
for (var key in drawControls){
    _map.removeControl(drawControls[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove control by using

`_map.removeControl(drawControls[key]);`